# 別ユーザーでインストールしたツールをPHPのexecで実行するとPermission deniedになる

Tags: php, linux, node.js

AmazonEC2に「svgexport」というツールをインストールしました。
https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport

上のURLに書いてあるとおり、
npm install svgexport -g
でインストールしたのですが、インストールされた場所が、ec2-userの下になってしまいました。

＜SSHでのインストール場所の確認＞

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-27 ~]$ which svgexport
~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/svgexport
```

恐らくそのせいと思うのですが、
PHPの中からexecでsvgexportを実行すると、Permission deniedで実行できません。

＜PHPからexecで実行した文＞

```
exec('/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/svgexport 
/var/www/html/test.svg /var/www/html/test.png');
```

＜ログに書き出した実行結果＞

```
$output= Array
(
    [0] => sh: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/svgexport: 
Permission denied
)
```

SSHでec2-userで直接コマンドを実行すると、正常に変換されます。

＜SSHで正常にいくコマンド＞

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-27 ~]$ /home/ec2-
user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/svgexport /var/www/html/test.svg 
/var/www/html/test.png
```

ec2-userで正常に実行できていますので、パーミッションの関係だと思うのですが、どうすればいいのかがわかりません。

どなたかご教授いただけますようお願いいたします。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

[追記]
コメントをいただきましたので、ec2-userのパーミッションを以下に追記させていただきます。

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-27 ~]$ ls -la
total 1208
drwx------ 14 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar 19 08:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root        4096 Feb 19 02:37 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar  8 05:27 .aws
-rw-------  1 ec2-user ec2-user   32482 Mar 19 07:19 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user      18 Aug 30  2017 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user     284 Mar 19 07:48 .bash_profile  
-rw-r--r--  1 ec2-user ec2-user     329 Mar 18 02:28 .bashrc
drwxrwxr-x  3 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Feb 19 06:23 .composer
drwx------  3 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar 13 05:40 .config
drwxrwxr-x 92 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar 19 07:50 .npm
drwxrwxr-x  9 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar 19 07:56 .nvm
```

これ以降、
.nvm、versions、node、v8.10.0、binまでのパーミッションは、drwxrwxr-xでした。
　　
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/binの中のパーミッションは以下になっていました。

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-27 bin]$ ls -la
total 34088
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user     4096 Mar 19 07:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 ec2-user ec2-user     4096 Mar 19 07:58 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 34895869 Mar  6 22:47 node
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user       38 Mar  6 22:47 npm -> 
../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user       38 Mar  6 22:47 npx -> 
../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user ec2-user       42 Mar 19 07:58 svgexport -> 
../lib/node_modules/svgexport/bin/index.js
```

../lib/node_modules/svgexport/bin/の中のパーミッションは以下の通りでした。

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-27 bin]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 19 07:58 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Mar 19 07:58 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user   62 Mar 19 07:58 index.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

確認してもらった内容を見る限りでは`ec2-user`のホームディレクトリのパーミッションが以下の様に`rwx------(700)`になっており、他のユーザーから参照できないのが原因だと思います。

```
drwx------ 14 ec2-user ec2-user    4096 Mar 19 08:08 .
```

実際にphpを実行するユーザ(webサーバ？)の権限で参照できるように、`group`や`other`に対してアクセス許可を付与してみてください。

```
$ chmod g+rx /home/ec2-user/
    又は
$ chmod go+rx /home/ec2-user/
```